# Pyspark find existing set of rows in a dataframe and replace it with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, replace, row

**I have a Pyspark dataframe_Old (dfo) as below:**

| Id | neighbor_sid | neighbor | division |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1100 | Naalehu | Hawaii |
| a2 | 1101 | key-west-fl | Miami |
| a3 | 1102 | lubbock | Texas |
| a10 | 1202 | bay-terraces | California |

**I have a Pyspark dataframe_new (dfn) as below:**

| Id | neighbor_sid | neighbor | division |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1100 | Naalehu | Hawaii |
| a2 | 1111 | key-largo-fl | Miami |
| a3 | 1103 | grapevine | Texas |
| a4 | 1115 | meriden-ct | Connecticut |
| a12 | 2002 | east-louisville | Kentucky |

My objective is to find the Ids from dataframe_new in dataframe_old and replace them with the new values from dataframe_new

**Final expected Pyspark dataframe updated - dataframe_old**

| Id | neighbor_sid | neighbor | division |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1100 | Naalehu | Hawaii |
| a2 | 1111 | key-largo-fl | Miami |
| a3 | 1103 | grapevine | Texas |
| a4 | 1115 | meriden-ct | Connecticut |
| a10 | 1202 | bay-terraces | California |
| a12 | 2002 | east-louisville | Kentucky |

**My wrong attempt at solving it as it is comparing column wise instead of row**

```
dfO.alias('a').join(dfN.alias('b'), on=['id'], how='left')\
    .select(
        'id',
        f.when(
            ~f.isnull(f.col('b.id')),
            f.col('b.id')
        ).otherwise(f.col('a.id')).alias('id'),
        'b.col_3'
    )\
    .union(dfO)\
    .dropDuplicates()\
    .sort('id')\
    .show()
```

Please help - would really appreciate any guidance!

Comment: this can be done using `outer` join and `coalesce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do an outer join on the `id` fields and then use `coalesce()` to prioritize the fields from `dfn`.

```
columns = ['id', 'neighbor_sid', 'neighbor', 'division']

dfo. \
    join(dfn, 'id', 'outer'). \
    select(*['id'] + [func.coalesce(dfn[k], dfo[k]).alias(k) for k in columns if k != 'id']). \
    orderBy('id'). \
    show()

# +---+------------+------------+-----------+
# | id|neighbor_sid|    neighbor|   division|
# +---+------------+------------+-----------+
# | a1|        1100|     Naalehu|     Hawaii|
# |a10|        1202|bay-terraces| California|
# | a2|        1111|key-largo-fl|      Miami|
# | a3|        1103|   grapevine|      Texas|
# | a4|        1115|  meriden-ct|Connecticut|
# +---+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi @samkart - thank you for guiding me. I have a usecase where the "dfn" has new values which were never present in "dfo" and its important to handle it in the final df (Edited my question to reflect this usecase). This would mean that `k in columns if k != 'id'` will not hold. How to go about this? Please help

Comment: the outer join handles the case where all records from both the dataframes are considered. just as the final dataframe in my examples shows. becasue `id` is handled by the join, we need not coalesce it anymore -- @Ridhi

Comment: @Ridhi - if you notice, "a10" is not present in the dfn, but it is present in the final df in my answer. similarly, all new values from both the dataframes willl be retained as a result of the outer join. the `k != 'id'` is just for the coalesce construction because `id` won't need a coalesce

Answer (score 0):

Id do a full outer join then coalesce to choose the second table where necessary:

```
# imports and creating data example
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
cols = ["id", "neighbor_sid", "neighbor", "division"]
data1 = [
    ["a1", 1100, 'Naalehu', 'Hawaii'],
    ["a2", 1101, 'key-west-fl', 'Miami'],
    ["a3", 1102, 'lubbock', 'Texas'],
    ["a10", 1202, 'bay-terraces', 'California'],
]

data2 = [
    ['a1',1100,'Naalehu','Hawaii'],
    ['a2',1111,'key-largo-fl','Miami'],
    ['a3',1103,'grapevine','Texas'],
    ['a4',1115,'meriden-ct','Connecticut'],
]
df0 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, cols)
dfN = spark.createDataFrame(data2, cols)


# solution
merge_df = df0.alias("a").join(dfN.alias('b'), on='id', how='outer')
d = (
    merge_df
    .select(
        "id",
        F.coalesce("b.neighbor_sid", "a.neighbor_sid").alias("neighbor_sid"),
        F.coalesce("b.neighbor", "a.neighbor").alias("neighbor"),
        F.coalesce("b.division", "a.division").alias("division")
    )
.sort("neighbor_sid")
)
display(d)
```